# C: reading file without system call open (only read!)

Tags: c, system-calls

I am just trying to read the data of a file into memory, but I want that my programme uses as less system calls as possible. That means that I am trying to avoid open or openat. I only want to use read. But I cannot find out how I can do that. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't read without opening first.

Answer (score 3):

`read` requires an open file descriptor, which you cannot get without calling either `open` or `openat` with the only exception being if you read from `stdin` (fd 0).

Updated to add:

Thankyou @Yunnosch for the suggestion. How about this:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html

NAME

```
pread, read - read from a file
```

SYNOPSIS

```
#include <unistd.h>

[XSI] [Option Start] ssize_t pread(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset); [Option End]

ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

DESCRIPTION

```
The read() function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, fildes, into the buffer pointed to by buf.
```

Comment: Can you back that up with a quote from standard or e.g. cppreference.com? Just to make a decent answer even better.